# Model field based on other fields?

Tags: django

Can I have a model field be based on other fields? For example:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    x = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    y = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    z = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=x+y+z)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, the best way to handle this would be to override the `save` method of the model

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    x = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    y = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    z = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.score = self.x + self.y + self.z
        super(Foo, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method.
```

Make sure you take care of the necessary validations.

More on this here: [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods)

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly for me... Now I am trying to interpret `models.BooleanField` as 0 or 1 integers to add up and score.

Comment: Just do `sum([...])` Example: `sum([True, False, True, True])` = 3

Answer (score 10):

How about this?

```
class Foo(models.Model):
     x = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
     y = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
     z = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

     @property
     def score(self):
         return self.x + self.y + self.z
```

Official docs on Model Methods [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#model-methods)

Comment: Great answer, especially when you can't rely on the .save() method being called in e.g., a batch update

Comment: Any way to use an object like this score in a list_filter?