# Set the primary_key based on two other fields in Django

Tags: django

I have the following model in which one the fields is based on other fields (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157437/model-field-based-on-other-fields)):

```
from django.db import models

class Model_Model01(models.Model):

    code_01 = models.CharField(max_length = 2, null = False, blank = False)
    code_02 = models.CharField(max_length = 3, null = False, blank = False)
    code_combined = models.CharField(max_length = 6, null = True, blank = False, primary_key = False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.code_combined = "{}.{}".format(self.code_01, self.code_02)
        super(Model_Model01, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.code_combined
```

I would like to set the primary_key of **code_combined** field as True after overriding the save method so I can use it as a foreignkey on other model. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not tell Django that you are using a composite key for this model using `unique_together`?

[Composite primary key in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712848/composite-primary-key-in-django)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#unique-together

```
class Model_Model01(models.Model):

    code_01 = models.CharField(max_length = 2, null = False, blank = False)
    code_02 = models.CharField(max_length = 3, null = False, blank = False)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('code_01', 'code_02',)
```

#### Update

Why not have the `code_combined` field be Unique, and reference it in your ForeignKey as the `to_field`?

```
class Model_Model01(models.Model):

    code_01 = models.CharField(max_length = 2, null = False, blank = False)
    code_02 = models.CharField(max_length = 3, null = False, blank = False)
    code_combined = models.CharField(max_length = 6, unique = True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.code_combined = "{}.{}".format(self.code_01, self.code_02)
        super(Model_Model01, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.code_combined


class Model_Model02(models.Model):
    model_1 = models.ForeignKey(Model_Model01, to_field='code_combined')
    ...
```

Beware of Unicode here; unless you are using Python 3!

Comment: Does "unique_together" work as a foreignkey of another model?

Comment: My fault on the incomplete question. I have edited the question for more clarity.

Comment: And it works. Thanks for providing this concise solution.

Comment: Sure! Happy to help :)